# iOS invert mask in drawRect

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics, drawrect, masking

With the code below, I am successfully masking part of my drawing, but it's the inverse of what I want masked. This masks the inner portion of the drawing, where I would like to mask the outer portion. Is there a simple way to invert this mask?

`myPath` below is a `UIBezierPath`.

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
CGMutablePathRef maskPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddPath(maskPath, nil, myPath.CGPath);
[maskLayer setPath:maskPath];
CGPathRelease(maskPath);
self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: On a deeper level this question is asking about fill rules, which determine which elements of intersecting paths are masked. I have found this link useful for those looking for more generalized answers and for my own understanding: https://www.calayer.com/core-animation/2016/05/22/cashapelayer-in-depth.html#fill-rule

Answer (score 42, accepted):

With even odd filling on the shape layer (`maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;`) you can add a big rectangle that covers the entire frame and then add the shape you are masking out. This will in effect invert the mask.

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
CGMutablePathRef maskPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(maskPath, NULL, someBigRectangle); // this line is new
CGPathAddPath(maskPath, nil, myPath.CGPath);
[maskLayer setPath:maskPath];
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;         // this line is new
CGPathRelease(maskPath);
self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: May be you can answer this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360389/use-layer-mask-to-make-parts-of-the-uiview-transparent

Comment: was CGPathRelease(maskPath) removed? its working but can i get a memory leak? (Swift 2.2, iOS 9.0) Couldn't find any reference to it.

Comment: That's correct, it won't cause a leak in Swift code. Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed in Swift. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html

Answer (score 19):

For Swift 3.0

```
func mask(viewToMask: UIView, maskRect: CGRect, invert: Bool = false) {
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    if (invert) {
        path.addRect(viewToMask.bounds)
    }
    path.addRect(maskRect)

    maskLayer.path = path
    if (invert) {
        maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    }

    // Set the mask of the view.
    viewToMask.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Based on the accepted answer, here's another mashup in Swift. I've made it into a function and made the `invert` optional

```
class func mask(viewToMask: UIView, maskRect: CGRect, invert: Bool = false) {
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    if (invert) {
        CGPathAddRect(path, nil, viewToMask.bounds)
    }
    CGPathAddRect(path, nil, maskRect)

    maskLayer.path = path
    if (invert) {
        maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    }

    // Set the mask of the view.
    viewToMask.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let red = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(red)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        red.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        red.mask(CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50), invert: true)
    }
}

extension UIView{

    func mask(_ rect: CGRect, invert: Bool = false) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        if (invert) {
            path.addRect(bounds)
        }
        path.addRect(rect)
        maskLayer.path = path
        if (invert) {
            maskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
        }
        // Set the mask of the view.
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

[image: 666]

Thanks @arvidurs

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks.  The gift that keeps on giving. :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's my Swift 4.2 solution that allows a corner radius

```swift
extension UIView {

    func mask(withRect maskRect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat, inverse: Bool = false) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        if (inverse) {
            path.addPath(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath)
        }
        path.addPath(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: maskRect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath)

        maskLayer.path = path
        if (inverse) {
            maskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
        }

        self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
    }

}
```

Comment: i think it should be `0` like so `roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 0`

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 4.2

```
func mask(viewToMask: UIView, maskRect: CGRect, invert: Bool = false) {
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    if (invert) {
        path.addRect(viewToMask.bounds)
    }
    path.addRect(maskRect)

    maskLayer.path = path
    if (invert) {
        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
    }

    // Set the mask of the view.
    viewToMask.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many great answers, all of them using even-odd rule for resolving interior and exterior surfaces. Here is Swift 5 approach with non-zero rule:

```
extension UIView {
    func mask(_ rect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat, invert: Bool = false) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        
        if (invert) {
            path.move(to: .zero)
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: .zero)
        }
        
        path.addPath(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath)
        maskLayer.path = path
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

For masking operation it is pretty straight forward. We draw rect and use it as masking path.

For inverted masking we use bounds of the view that is going to be masked. Then we draw it counter clockwise. After that we add `UIBezierPath` rect, which is by default drawn clockwise. That way any point p inside the rect will have one clockwise intersection and one counter clockwise intersection, leading to total winding number of zero, making that point an exterior point.

Answer (score 1):

### For 2023. All answers currently here seem wrong as they don't adjust the mask when the layout changes (or - just one example - when the view is animating in size or shape).

It's very simple ..

**1.** have a layer (perhaps just a square of color, an image, whatever)

```
lazy var examp: CALayer = {
    let l = CALayer()
    l.background = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    l.mask = shapeAsMask
    layer.addSublayer(l)
    return l
}()
```

Note that `examp` has its mask set already.

**2.**  Whenever you want to mask, you of course need a masking layer on hand

```
lazy var shapeAsMask: CAShapeLayer = {
    let s = CAShapeLayer()
    s.fillRule = .evenOdd
    layer.addSublayer(s)
    layer.mask = s
    return s
}()
```

Note that the fillrule is set as needed.

**3.** Now make a shape with a bezier curve. Let's just make a circle:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    examp.frame = bounds

    let i = bounds.width * 0.30
    let thing = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds.insetBy(dx: i, dy: i))
    ...
}
```

So that's a small circle in the middle of the view.

### If you want to "have the shape" it's just

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    fill.frame = bounds

    let i = bounds.width * 0.30
    let thing = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds.insetBy(dx: i, dy: i))
    
    shapeAsMask.path = thing.cgPath
}
```

### If you want to "have the INVERSE OF the shape" it's just

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    fill.frame = bounds

    let i = bounds.width * 0.30
    let thing = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds.insetBy(dx: i, dy: i))

    let p = CGMutablePath()
    p.addRect(bounds)
    p.addPath(thing.cgPath)

    shapeAsMask.path = p
}
```

In short, the "negative" of this ..

```
let thing = UIBezierPath( ... some path
```

is just this:

```
let neg = CGMutablePath()
neg.addRect(bounds)
neg.addPath(thing.cgPath)
```

So that's it.

## Don't forget that ...

Anytime you have a mask (or a layer!) you have to set it in `layoutSubviews`.  (That's why layoutSubviews is named layoutSubviews !)

Answer (score 0):

In order to invert mask you can to something like this

1. Here I have mask of crossed rectancles like

   ```
    let crossPath =  UIBezierPath(rect: cutout.insetBy(dx: 30, dy: -5))
             crossPath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: cutout.insetBy(dx: -5, dy: 30)))
               let crossMask = CAShapeLayer()
               crossMask.path = crossPath.cgPath
               crossMask.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
               crossMask.fillRule = .evenOdd
   ```
2. And here I add 3rd rectancle around my crossed rectancles 
   so using .evenOdd it takes area that is equal to (New Rectancle - Old Crossed Rectangle) so in other words outside area of crossed rectancles

   ```
     let crossPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cutout.insetBy(dx: -5, dy: -5) )
       crossPath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: cutout.insetBy(dx: 30, dy: -5)))
       crossPath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: cutout.insetBy(dx: -5, dy: 30)))
       let crossMask = CAShapeLayer()
       crossMask.path = crossPath.cgPath
       crossMask.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
       crossMask.fillRule = .evenOdd
   ```

[image]