# SwiftUI add inverted mask

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to add a mask to two shapes such that the second shape masks out the first shape. If I do something like `Circle().mask(Circle().offset(…))`, this has the opposite affect: preventing anything outside the first circle from being visible.

For `UIView` the answer is here: [iOS invert mask in drawRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411765/ios-invert-mask-in-drawrect)

However, trying to implement this in SwiftUI *without* `UIView` eludes me. I tried implementing an InvertedShape with I could then use as a mask:

```swift
struct InvertedShape<OriginalType: Shape>: Shape {
    let originalShape: OriginalType

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let mutableOriginal = originalShape.path(in: rect).cgPath.mutableCopy()!
        mutableOriginal.addPath(Path(rect).cgPath)
        return Path(mutableOriginal)
            .evenOddFillRule()
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, SwiftUI paths do not have `addPath(Path)` (because they are immutable) or `evenOddFillRule()`. You can access the path's CGPath and make a mutable copy and then add the two paths, however, `evenOddFillRule` needs to be set on the `CGLayer`, not the `CGPath`. So unless I can get to the CGLayer, I'm unsure how to proceed.

This is Swift 5.

Comment: SwiftUI paths _do_ have addPath(Path), as well as even-odd fill rule, see below my answer.

Comment: @Asperi I could have sworn I checked for addPath, I guess I had an immutable copy for some reason...

Comment: @Asperi it looks like _`Path`s_ don't have fill rules, but `Shape`s do.

Comment: In SwiftUI Path 'is a' Shape.

Comment: @Asperi true. The issue though is that `.fill` returns a view, not a path... So that was a problem with my implementation, because I kinda wanted to return a path or shape... But that was not really needed, I just thought it was.

Comment: A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63934218/5409815): - [Inverted mask swiftui with system image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63934218/5409815)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach of creating inverted mask, by SwiftUI only, (on example to make a hole in view)

[image: SwiftUI hole mask, reverse mask]

```
func HoleShapeMask(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    var shape = Rectangle().path(in: rect)
    shape.addPath(Circle().path(in: rect))
    return shape
}

struct TestInvertedMask: View {

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 100)
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: rect.width, height: rect.height)
            .mask(HoleShapeMask(in: rect).fill(style: FillStyle(eoFill: true)))
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I know it isn't relevant but is it possible to add this shape to a ZStack and allow user to interact only through the Hole with the content in background?

Answer (score 32):

Here's another way to do it, which is more Swiftly.

The trick is to use:

```
YourMaskView()
   .compositingGroup()
   .luminanceToAlpha()
```

`maskedView.mask(YourMaskView())`

Just create your mask with Black and White shapes, black will be transparent, white opaque, anything in between is going to be semi-transparent.

`.compositingView()`, similar to `.drawingGroup()`, rasterises the view (converts it to a bitmap texture). By the way, this also happens when you `.blur` or do any other pixel-level operations.

`.luminanceToAlpha()` takes the RGB luminance levels (I guess by averaging the RGB values), and maps them to the Alpha (opacity) channel of the bitmap.

Comment: this works great when YourMaskView is black & white, thanks

Comment: Maybe SwiftUI has updated, but I just attempted to follow this and `.compositingGroup()` and `.luminanceToAlpha()` is no longer needed. It was causing it to not work in my case.

Instead, just ensuring my mask view is black and white, then calling `maskedView.mask(YourMaskView())` did the job.

Comment: My mask view consists of drawing a path. It is possible it has built-in alpha.

Answer (score 24):

Use [**.blendMode**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/blendmode(_:)) modifier

```
ZStack {
      Rectangle() // destination
      Circle()    // source
        .blendMode(.destinationOut)
    }
    .compositingGroup()
```

Comment: As this is porter-duff blending, is it different from other options?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner this is Apple's native modifier which has been available since the first version of SwiftUI (ios 13). See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/blendmode(_:)), there are a lot of options for using this modifier.

Comment: definitely the most simple and elegant way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `.compositionGroup()` modifier! I was wondering why my blended out shape was appearing black when I was moving my app in background or when I was sharing my phone's screen using QuickTime Player. Turns out I was just missing this modifier on the parent View.

Answer (score 12):

Using a mask such as in the accepted answer is a good approach. Unfortunately, masks do not affect hit testing. Making a shape with a hole can be done in the following way.

```
extension Path {
    var reversed: Path {
        let reversedCGPath = UIBezierPath(cgPath: cgPath)
            .reversing()
            .cgPath
        return Path(reversedCGPath)
    }
}

struct ShapeWithHole: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Rectangle().path(in: rect)
        let hole = Circle().path(in: rect).reversed
        path.addPath(hole)
        return path
    }
}
```

The trick is to reverse the path for the hole. Unfortunately `Path` does not (yet) support reversing the path out-of-the-box, hence the extension (which uses `UIBezierPath`). The shape can then be used for clipping and hit-testing purposes:

```
struct MaskedView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
            .clipShape(ShapeWithHole())    // clips or masks the view
            .contentShape(ShapeWithHole()) // needed for hit-testing
    }
}
```

Comment: This will create the exclusion of the paths in a single Shape. It does not affect overlapping multiple shapes (though you can get the same visual effect with this method).

Comment: cool. for my use case though I think still need a mask because I need to mask a stroked shape, and the strokes need to fit the clip mask exactly.  (don't have my code ATM to play around with technique, but I like the idea)

Comment: Masking is fine and you can still combine both methods if you need hit testing to respect the shape.

Answer (score 12):

Based on [this article](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/reverse-masks-how-to/), here's a `.reverseMask` modifier you can use instead of `.mask`. I modified it to support iOS 13 and up.

```
extension View {
    @inlinable func reverseMask<Mask: View>(
        alignment: Alignment = .center,
        @ViewBuilder _ mask: () -> Mask
    ) -> some View {
            self.mask(
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle()

                    mask()
                        .blendMode(.destinationOut)
                }
            )
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
ViewToMask()
.reverseMask {
    MaskView()
}
```

Comment: You may need to add `.compositingGroup()` after the `ZStack`.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this yet, but could you do something like this:

```
extension UIView {
    func mask(_ rect: CGRect, invert: Bool = false) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let path = CGMutablePath()

        if (invert) {
            path.addRect(bounds)
        }
        path.addRect(rect)
        maskLayer.path = path

        if (invert) {
            maskLayer.fillRule = CAShapeLayerFillRule.evenOdd
        }

        // Set the mask of the view.
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}

struct MaskView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var child: UIHostingController<ImageView>
    @Binding var rect: CGRect
    @Binding var invert: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MaskView>) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()

        self.child.view.mask(self.rect, invert: self.invert)

        view.addSubview(self.child.view)

        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MaskView>) {

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ImageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("image1")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var child = UIHostingController(rootView: ImageView())
    @State var rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
    @State var invert: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            MaskView(child: self.$child, rect: self.$rect, invert: self.$invert)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a refinement on [@Asperi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59659733/1067774): if you don't want to pass an explicit size to the shape mask, you can use SwiftUI's `Shape` type to achieve the same result:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.black)
            .mask(HoleShape().fill(style: FillStyle(eoFill: true)))
    }
}

struct HoleShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var shape = Rectangle().path(in: rect)
        shape.addPath(Circle().path(in: rect))
        return shape
    }
}
```