# SwiftUI inverted mask

Tags: swiftui, mask, cgrect

I'm trying to create an view like in the screenshot with swiftui. The top frame should be light, other places should be dark.
[SwiftUI add inverted mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656117/swiftui-add-inverted-mask)
I tried to change it over the codes here, but I couldn't. how can i do it?

[image]

where I've come so far :
black color not show full screen and mask not working

```
func HoleShapeMask(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
    return
        Path { path in
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var rect :CGRect = .zero

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader{g in
            Text("deneme")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: 124, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.red)
                .overlay(
                    GeometryReader { gp in
                        Color.clear.opacity(0.00001)
                            .onAppear(){
                                rect = gp.frame(in: .named("deneme"))
                            }
                    }
                )
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "deneme")
        .overlay(
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.8))
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .mask(HoleShapeMask(in: rect).fill(style: FillStyle(eoFill: true)))
        )
    }
}
```

my code screenshot :
[image: mycodesc]

i want to this screen :
[image: wanti]

Comment: You should show your existing code and your attempt and people can look for where things went awry. Otherwise, there's no reason that a new answer will be any different than the answer you already linked to, which you say doesn't work for you.

Comment: thanks. i added my code