# View in Swiftui with an image and an overlay rectangle with borders

Tags: swift, image, swiftui

I am using the code below and its working fine but i need to make the overlay rectangle with the borders show up as in the image below instead of having the black opacity 0.3. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Code found in another post in StackOverflow

```swift
    struct CropFrame: Shape {
        let isActive: Bool
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            guard isActive else { return Path(rect) } // full rect for non active
    
            let size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.screenWidth * 0.7, height: UIScreen.screenHeight/5)
            let origin = CGPoint(x: rect.midX - size.width / 2, y: rect.midY - size.height / 2)
            return Path(CGRect(origin: origin, size: size).integral)
        }
    }
    
    struct CropImage: View {
    
        @State private var currentPosition: CGSize = .zero
        @State private var newPosition: CGSize = .zero
        @State private var clipped = false
    
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Image("test_pic")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .offset(x: self.currentPosition.width, y: self.currentPosition.height)
    
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.black.opacity(0.3))
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth * 0.7 , height: UIScreen.screenHeight/5)
                        .overlay(Rectangle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 3))
                }
                .clipShape(
                    CropFrame(isActive: clipped)
                )
                .gesture(DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width, height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
    
                    self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
                })
    
    
                Button (action : { self.clipped.toggle() }) {
                    Text("Crop Image")
                        .padding(.all, 10)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 1)
                        .padding(.top, 50)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here's a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656117/swiftui-add-inverted-mask. Here's a quick sample of how it might work: https://gist.github.com/Baglan/1f8ac704e41fc98d6f891d777b63f566. Let me know if more is needed :)

Comment: I don't really understand your question here.
 If you don't want to use `.fill(Color.black.opacity(0.3))` then use something else
 like `.fill(Color.clear)`