# Clipping a resized image using aspectRatio scaling SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

At the end of the day, I'm trying to scale to fill an image into a height of X (439px in my case) and then clip it using a RoundedRectangle.

```
post.picture
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(height: 439)
    .clipped()
    .clipShape(Circle())
```

This view is inside a VStack. If that is necessary to resolve this, I'll post it too, but I don't think it is.

`post.picture` is an `Image` property within the `Post` struct. It looks like this

```
struct Post: Hashable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var userId: Int
    var location: String
    var activityId: Int
    var cheerCount: Int
    
    private var pictureLocation: String
    var picture: Image {
        let mainPath = "/hardcoded/path/"
        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "\(mainPath)/\(pictureLocation)") {
            return Image(uiImage: image)
        } else {
            return Image(systemName: "photo")
        }
    }
}
```

The code produces this

[image]

The issue is that the circle is cut off at the edges. I want the circle mask to be scaled down but the image to retain it's aspect ratio and size.

I am not sure how to do this. I'm using a clipShape(Circle()) to make the issue more clear but I really want to clip the image with RoundedRectangle.

The code works properly when the `image` height is larger than width, and cuts off the mask shape when the width larger than the height.

It's suppose to look like this

[image]

Comment: So basically, the issue is that the image in the first one isn't actually resizing. Is this correct?

Comment: Also, have you tried using [`.scaledToFit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scaledtofit()) instead of `aspectRatio`?

Comment: I think your issue is the dimensions of your image. I presume they are not standardized, and are probably wider than high. In that case, a clip shape won't work. What you need is to make a cover with a hole in it. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59659733/7129318).

Comment: @MrDeveloper no, the issue is the mask is scaled with the fit/aspect ratio so it gets cut off.

Comment: @Yrb I'm having trouble using that solution on my own. How would your linked solution look in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

```
post.picture
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(
        minWidth: 0,
        maxWidth: .infinity,
        minHeight: 439,
        maxHeight: 439
    )
    .clipped()
    .clipShape(Circle())
```

Answer (score 0):

Best avoid using `UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width` for setting view dimensions due to two reasons:

1. The use of `main` will be deprecated in future iOS versions.
2. It represents a static value that does not adapt to device orientation changes, such as rotating.

In SwiftUI, parent views do not inherently dictate the size and position of child views. This becomes particularly relevant when dealing with images set to `scaledToFill`. This setting causes an image to expand until one of its dimensions aligns with the corresponding dimension of its parent view. However, without explicit constraints, this can lead to the image exceeding the bounds of the parent view if the other dimension is smaller. I think this is the biggest difference from image behaviours in UIKit.

So, we'd better explicitly define the dimensions of images. This ensures that they do not unexpectedly exceed the parent view's bounds. Here, the `GeometryReader` plays a role by providing access to the parent view's size, which reflects the available screen area for the image. This allows for dynamic sizing of the image based on the device's screen dimensions or the parent view's size.

Consider the following code snippet:

```swift
GeometryReader { geometry in
    post.picture
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 439)
        .clipped()
        .cornerRadius(10)
}
// Apply padding or other modifiers below this line. As GeometryReader acts as a container view and may affect layout.
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I figured it out.

The `frame(height: 439)` and `.fill` caused the internal `width` value of the frame to be extended *past* the screen limits in order to keep the aspect ratio when the `width > height`.

This made it so the left and right edges of the frame were cut off when `width > height`. This seems like silly behaviour to me since there is nothing to indicate that the frame is larger than the screen width. Visually, the image looks clipped to the correct size, and documentation wise would imply this should work properly without explicitly setting the frame size (given that the max width of the VStack should be the width of the screen).

To fix it, I needed to place an explicit width size on the frame

```
post.picture
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 439)
    .clipped()
    .cornerRadius(10)
```

`.infinity` doesn't work on the width like @Fuad suggested because that would only scale the frame to it's already large width. The frame needed to be cropped essentially.

Comment: That is essentially it, though for the `.frame()` I would consider using `maxWidth:, maxHeight:`